# Exporting groups of layers from a PSD to a single PNG file using Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

What is the fastest way by which I can save a group of layers as a single `.png` file with empty spaces around the group of layers trimmed. I know I can run a script to export every single layer to a `.png` file, but can I set it to extract only selected layers and save them in one `.png` file?

Comment: The difficulty of all the answers relative to just using Fireworks in the first place makes it really obviouls what a mistake Adobe has made discontinuing FW.

Answer (score 16):

- Select the particular layers you want to save as a `.png` file
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> (that'll merge them into a single layer)
- `select all` and `copy`
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to create new file.

The default option in Photoshop is that the size of the new file will be the same as what you've in clip-board. In this case, it'll give you a size with the empty spaces trimmed.

Now paste your clip-board content and save as `.png`.

Comment: merging into a single layer and slicing it is as good as dragging them all into a new blank psd file. i'm not able to get the default size of the new blank file to the size of the layers in the clipboard though. is there a setting i need to do? i'm using CS5 on a mac.

Comment: It's about speed @Shyam. Slicing is a manual process and is slow and there are chances of error in identifying transparent pixels. The process I'm talking about is as simple as "ctrl+a", "ctrl+c", "ctrl+n", "enter", "ctrl+v", "ctrl+alt+shift+s". Here, photoshop identifies all transparent pixels automatically and gives you the perfect bounding box size automatically.

Comment: I'm not a mac user but for windows, make sure that the preset option in the "create new file" dialogue box is set to custom to get the clipboard size. Refer point no 5 in the [link](http://goo.gl/Ib5j9)

Answer (score 2):

Try turning off the layers you don't want and saving as a `.png` file  with `save for web`. That way you have a little control on the final resolution output. Or are you looking for a batch type of saving method?

Comment: not the best thing to do when there are like a hundred layers and many more sublayers inside. yes, a script!! is there a script for the love of god?!

Comment: Yes, a script would be great for this, but in playing devils advocate, how would the script know which layers to ignore?  just curios are they the same layers in all images?  If so possibly `photoshop` `comps` would be a way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Found [this script called Layer Saver](http://www.scriptsrus.talktalk.net/Layer%20Saver.htm) when searching for a solution to this same problem.

> This script will allow you to save layers/layersets to different
>   formats PNG, PSD, PDF, TIF, JPG or JPG Save For Web. A different menu
>   is given depending if only layers or layersets found.

[image]

Works like a charm and offers many different formats!

Comment: Can you please explain in a few words what the script is doing?  Your answer forces one to leave this site...

Comment: Hi Mary! I added a short quote and image from that site so it's easier to see what the script does. Feel free to re-edit or add more info if you think it's important. Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Another method to do this is to create "Layer Comps" and from scripts export each Layer Comp as a file.

I'm sorry, I'm new here, so I do not know how to put in advanced formatting and images, so my answer may seem pretty empty.

Comment: Until you've gained some points from participating in the community, you won't be able to post images. If you can provide to a link to the image? Maybe someone can edit it into your answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can record an action such as:

- first select the layers you DON'T want to see/export.
- choose "group from layers..." in the layers palette menu name it something like FOOTEMPLAYERSGROUPBLARGLE
- hide the group
- {...}
- export
- close, NO SAVE (the grouping will re-arrange those selected layers in first step)
- OR instead of close, no save, REVERT
- {profit}

EDIT:

AND after you record it, then you merely crop to the area you want, select the layers you don't want, and then run the action.

Answer (score 0):

Make only the layers you want to use visible, then go to `File > Save for Web & Devices`. Once there select `.png` from the dropdown menu. You will now have the ability to tweak many of the settings (color depth, quality, etc.) including transparency. This keeps your original file as is and creates a new file with your desired settings. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is :

- Select the required layers & disable all other layers
- select trim from `image>trim`
- Save this as a `.png` file using `File > Save as`
- undo Trim action using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
- Repeat for other layers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is cool. Group your layers into a single group then right click the group in the layers palette and choose 'export as'. You get to choose scale, format and quality. The resulting image will be named the same as the name of your group.

Now the really cool bit. If you have lots of layers in lots of groups - shift (or control) select the groups you wish to export and then do the same as above (by right clicking on any of your selected groups). They will all be exported at once and will be named the same as your groups.

This all works with single layers or grouped layers too. Just select whatever you want in the layers palette.

[image: Export as dialogue box]

Comment: Does this export every layer as a separate file? Because that's not what the question asks for. Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the group, and go to *Layers > Quick Export as PNG* *(Shift + CMD/CTRL + ')* that will automatically merge the group's content and export it as PNG. Hope this helps.